# Pyautogui not entering all characters when using typewrite function

Tags: high-sierra, python

we are trying to automate the SecurityAgent dialog where we are inputting password using pyautogui in 10.13 OSx

password = "12345678"
using

```
pyautogui.typewrite(password)
```

this function solved the problem. However, we are running this script many number of times in the same machine

Am not sure if it is because of the machine slowness or something , only 7 characters are getting written on the screen and enter is clicked which fails the step.

i also tried adding interval and pause value in pyautogui. But it doesnt help. Randomly script is failing.

Instead of typing a whole sequence i tried to run a loop like below

```
for c in password:
  pyautogui.press(c)
```

Still it didnt help. Can someone help with the alternate solution ?

Answer (score 2):

With AppleScript I made this for use in Automator:

https://gist.github.com/SuperHofstad/f826985ec536ff2d650699cb37a7fadc

```
set appPass to "PASSWORD" as text

tell application "System Events"
    delay 0.5
    repeat until exists process "SecurityAgent"
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    tell process "SecurityAgent"
        keystroke appPass
        key code 36
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Not perfect, but the code is a start. Might get around to make it better some other time..

Answer (score 1):

You may be typing too fast. Try `pyautogui.typewrite(password, interval=0.2)`

Comment: Upvote for this answer.
My situation was similar as OP's: 

in *some* cases when typing a string, the first character of the sentence (which is always the same 2 characters) the first character will get eaten.

With the suggestion above applied, the problem immediately completely disappeared.

Conclusion: pyautogui.typewrite will type *too fast*, some times, and the duplicated character gets eaten as duplicate keystroke detection.